# `eb init` fails with pkg_resources.ContextualVersionConflict PyYAML 4.1

Tags: python, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, bitbucket-pipelines

I am having some trouble deploying my elastic beanstalk app from a bitbucket pipeline. This same code had been working without issue, so my best guess is some kind of dependency issue.

(awsebcli version 3.14.1)

The image for the pipeline is `python:3.5.2`
and here's the failing step:

```
- step:
      name: Test Deploy
      deployment: test
      caches:
        - pip
      script:
        - pip install awsebcli --upgrade
        - eb init myAppName -r us-east-1 -p Python  # This line started failing :'(
        - eb deploy myAppName-dev-1
```

and the error output:

`eb init myAppName -r us-east-1 -p Python
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 570, in _build_master
    ws.require(__requires__)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 888, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 779, in resolve
    raise VersionConflict(dist, req).with_context(dependent_req)
pkg_resources.ContextualVersionConflict: (PyYAML 4.1 (/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages), Requirement.parse('PyYAML<4,>=3.10'), {'docker-compose'})
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/eb", line 6, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3095, in <module>
    @_call_aside
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3079, in _call_aside
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3108, in _initialize_master_working_set
    working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 572, in _build_master
    return cls._build_from_requirements(__requires__)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 585, in _build_from_requirements
    dists = ws.resolve(reqs, Environment())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 779, in resolve
    raise VersionConflict(dist, req).with_context(dependent_req)
pkg_resources.ContextualVersionConflict: (PyYAML 4.1 (/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages), Requirement.parse('PyYAML<4,>=3.10'), {'docker-compose'})`

So if I'm reading this right, I have PyYAML 4.1 when I need something less than 4.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I changed the pip install line to explicitly use an older version of PyYAML and that seems to have worked...

Changed

```
pip install awsebcli --upgrade
```

To

```
pip install pyYAML==3.12 awsebcli --upgrade
```

Comment: Youuuuuuu ROCK!

Comment: Great. Thanks!!

Comment: `awsebcli` 3.14.2 ties the `pyyaml` version to 3.12. So upgrading to 3.14.2 should fix the problem too.